# Loop Remover feature in Opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

L2switch feature is not available in Fluorine, which is the current version of Opendaylight. How does Opendaylight Fluorine prevent Layer 2 loops and floods without the Loop Remover functionality of L2switch?

Comment: What have you tried researching?

Answer (score 0):

l2switch is not longer maintained and not included in Fluorine. You'll need to use
older versions of ODL to get it. There may be a way to bring it in to Fluorine, but
I don't know that process. Keep in mind that ODL is not only about openflow or layer
2 loop removal, etc.